# Compaction - TimeWindowCompactionStrategy Cassandra 3

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to migrate Cassandra 2 to 3, but I am having troubles with `TimeWindowCompactionStrategy`.

Cassandra 2

```
compaction = {'compaction_window_size': '3', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'}
```

Any idea in Cassandra 3? Thank you!

Comment: What troubles? what version of 2, what version of 3?

Answer (score 2):

Following works for me in Cassandra 3.0

```
compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '3', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS'}
```